# Python API - Reattaching transactions after snapshot

Tags: address, iri-legacy-api, snapshot, attach-to-tangle, balances

I have a small seed for testing using the Python API, linking to a local CarrIOTA node. The seed has only one used address.

If I run `get_account_data()`, the balance shows as 0 since I haven't reattached any transactions yet.

With `get_inputs(start=0, stop=1,threshold=0)`, I can see the Address and totalBalance that I want to reattach, but how can I find the transaction info so I can use `attach_to_tangle`?

`get_balances(address)` gives me the address, balance, a reference (which seems to be the same for all addresses), the current milestoneIndex, and 'milestone'=None. and `find_transactions(address)` returns an empty hash.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Following from the light wallet:

https://github.com/iotaledger/wallet/blob/4a50e49c15c76ec57793614eafaa2edf54352927/ui/js/ui.addresses.js#L55
https://github.com/iotaledger/wallet/blob/4a50e49c15c76ec57793614eafaa2edf54352927/ui/js/ui.addresses.js#L77

and the cli-wallet (line 41):
https://github.com/iotaledger/cli-app/blob/master/lib/commands/address.js

it seems that when you press generate address, `get_new_addresses` is called, and then a 0 value transfer is sent from the address to itself while you are waiting for "attaching to tangle"

I ran:

```
print(api.get_account_data()['balance'])
adds = api.get_new_addresses(0,1)['addresses']

print(api.send_transfer(
  depth = 3,
  transfers = [
    ProposedTransaction(
      address = Address(adds[0],),
      value = 0,
    ),
  ],
)
print(api.get_account_data()['balance'])
```

which returned:

```
0
{u'bundle': <iota.transaction.base.Bundle object at 0xXXXXX>}
1
```

Additionally, `get_transfers(0,1)` now shows a bundle!

Answer (score 0):

If your transaction confirmed, there is no need to reattach it after the snapshot.

If it did not confirm, you'd have to create a new transaction.

Anyway all transactions are "gone" now, so if you did not store the trytes before the snapshot, there is no way to reattach them now via API.

Comment: Is there an API equivalent to the generate address/attach process that you have to do manually using a light wallet? How does the light wallet grab the pre-snapshot balances? 

The transaction confirmed and was available well before the snapshot.

Comment: In:
https://github.com/iotaledger/wallet/blob/4a50e49c15c76ec57793614eafaa2edf54352927/ui/js/ui.addresses.js#L55

https://github.com/iotaledger/wallet/blob/4a50e49c15c76ec57793614eafaa2edf54352927/ui/js/ui.addresses.js#L77

It seems that the wallet sends a 0 value transaction to itself and then shows "attaching to tangle". I wander whether this would work, but I would rather not lose the balance completely

Comment: yes, that works. Just send 0 value transactions to all your addresses and the wallet will see the balance again. The balance is still there for other tools to use even without reattaching.